# Replacing consecutive whitespace with one whitespace character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to replace two or more occurrences of whitespace with just one whitespace character using JavaScript (this code is going to sit inside a chrome extension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"    this is    tooo    spaced      ".replace(/\s+/g, " ");
```

returns

```
" this is tooo spaced "
```

Comment: This matches one *or* more. The OP was looking for "more than one". `/\s{2,}/g` would make more sense (though yours still works).

Answer (score 3):

You can do both at once with:

```
"str   str\t\t\tstr".replace(/(\s)+/g, "$1");
```

Comment: Didn't know that \s matched \t as well. Impressive!

Comment: @Davide  how would I go about replacing tabs with space now? do I do an other loop?

Comment: If you want all white space characters replaced by a space, you should simply use what davin wrote. I added my example because I thought you wanted multiple tabs to be replaced by a tab, multiple spaces by a space, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For spaces:

```
'test   with   spaces'.replace( /\s+/g, ' ' );
```

For tabs:

```
'test\t\t\twith\t\t\ttabs'.replace( /\t+/g, '\t' );
```